# ignore empty <p> </p> tags in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have jquery code that puts borders around `<p>` tags but it is also doing so for `<p>` tags with no text or child nodes in them. I was wondering if I could ignore `<p>` tags that have no content inside them. Would "not has" be considered here?

p tags with spaces should also be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("p:not(:empty)").css("border", "1px solid red");
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/sVSD4/)

Comment: I was making a fiddle for my _own_ answer but hell, have it: http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/2SfY5/ :-P

Comment: @Shef - I greased my keyboard today ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('p:not(:empty)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector to find elements with no children (including text nodes).

```
$('p:not(:empty)')
```

Note that *any* text content -- even a single white space -- will be selected by this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore whitespace as well you can do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").filter(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).text()) !== '';
    }).addClass("class-with-border");
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nnVCF/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need the `:empty` selector. Like this:

```
$("p:not(:empty)").css("border", "1px solid #F00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("p:not(:empty)");//It will select all the tags which hav children
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selectors

```
$('p:not(:empty)')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("p").each(function(index,value){
if($(value).html()!="")$(value).css({border:"1px solid black"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `:empty` selector

```
$('p:empty').remove();
```